# Is there a limit on displaying images served through mongodb gridFS?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am just testing how well can mongodb gridFS handle image requests. The snippet gets the images from gridFS and displays them on a web page. The problem here, when I increase the limit from 25, images are not displayed. Is there a serving limit on gridFs or is my approach for testing wrong?

```
$gridFS = $db->getGridFS();
$objects = $gridFS->find()->limit(25);

while($object = $objects->getNext()){

    echo " <img src=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$object->file['id']."\"> ";

}

if(isset($id) AND $id!=""){ 
    $gridFSa = $db->getGridFS();
    $object = $gridFSa->findOne(array('id'=>new MongoId($id)) );
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($object)); 
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 
    ob_clean(); 
    echo $object->getBytes();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you increase the limit?
Do you get an error in your PHP logs?

Comment: Have you ever tried objects->hasNext() ?

Comment: @bjori : There is no error in php logs; I gave up using gridfs.

Comment: @algorian: I tried hasNext();  Anyway, I gave up using gridFs for images and decided to use filesystem.